# Нужно очистить файл txt каждые 10 часов

Tags: php

Нужно очистить файл txt каждые 10 часов . Подскажите как реализовать,

В файле messages.txt будут записываться сообщения из чата , поэтому нужно очищать файл каждые 10 часов, чтобы небыло мусора много, а то через месяц будет сайт зависать